# Can't use fetch in nodejs to make the API request

Tags: node.js, next.js, axios, fetch-api

I'm using fetch to make the POST request to retrieve the data from an API in server side (nextjs 13 + node 18).

I'm able to get the data via postman and axios but not fetch.

The following is the code i use:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Accept", "application/json");
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "id_token xxx");
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");

var raw = JSON.stringify({});

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: raw,
};

fetch("{url}", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response)
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

Comment: What is the error? I bet it's something CORS related

Comment: `response` is a stream so you're just passing it back doing nothing. Therefore when you log `result` it should print the response object as is. To see the result you would need to extract it from the response object using either `response.json()` or `response.text()` or `response.blob()` or `response.arrayBuffer()` etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out, it's because of the node fetch API include some default headers and the API service seems doesn't support it.

I can replicate the same response in postman if I include this header.

In my case the header is: Accept-Language: *